Issues on retrieving Access Token for Azure Marketplace Metered Billing API for azure managed application
I'm building a centralized metered billing system for an Azure Managed Application. My setup collects user data, aggregates it, performs calculations, and then sends the metered billing data to the Azure Marketplace API endpoint from our centralized service.
I'm having trouble obtaining an access token for the metered billing APIs using the request body outlined in the following docs. I am using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace-offers/marketplace-metering-service-authentication#request-body this request body. And I am unsure about the Resource part in the request body.
I used the following request body as form value with header application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

"Grant_type": "client_credentials",
"Client_id": "<client_id>",
"client_secret": "<client_secret>",
"Resource": "00001111-aaaa-2222-bbbb-3333cccc4444"

And I am getting the following error. 

{
    "error": "invalid_resource",
    "error_description": "AADSTS500011: The resource principal named 00001111-aaaa-2222-bbbb-3333cccc4444 was not found in the tenant named AppsCode Inc.. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant. Trace ID: a44ac10b-2e2f-4b3d-b953-7abc54eb0c00 Correlation ID: 36b0dcac-393a-4f16-8363-2285cf66ec12 Timestamp: 2024-10-25 12:48:53Z",
    "error_codes": [
        500011
    ],
    "timestamp": "2024-10-25 12:48:53Z",
    "trace_id": "a44ac10b-2e2f-4b3d-b953-7abc54eb0c00",
    "correlation_id": "36b0dcac-393a-4f16-8363-2285cf66ec12",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=500011"
}

I believe that We have already configured the necessary permissions for the application used in our marketplace offer. Could anyone provide any insights into what might be missing or misconfigured on our end?

Check the resource id is correct?

The Resource is same as mentioned in the doc (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/partner-center/marketplace-offers/marketplace-metering-service-authentication#request-body).

Have you tried with https://management.azure.com?

Which API needs to access ?

But using the token got with the scope https://management.azure.com/.default doesn't work on the api endpoint "https://marketplaceapi.microsoft.com/api/usageEvent?api-version=2018-08-31" as expected. @Venkatesan any idea how can I fix it?

It need to be different i guess tho.

Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1456743/confused-with-resourceid-used-in-saas-v2-saas-v2-r
